Using Ansible to modify pom.xml
I want to modify the pom.xml files on the fly to make Maven use the locally-installed JARs for a specific groupId. So, I need to:

Change/set the scope of each matching dependency to system.
Add the systemPath to each matching dependency, pointing it to a file, the name of which will be a function of the artifactId.

For example, the
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
                       <artifactId>myGroup-agent-api</artifactId>
                       <version>3.1.38.13</version>
                       <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

needs to become:
                <dependency>
                       <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
                       <artifactId>myGroup-agent-api</artifactId>
                       <version>3.1.38.13</version>
                       <scope>system</scope>
                       <systemPath>${application_path}/jar/agent-api.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>

The first part I figured out. This Ansible-task using the xml-module should be changing/setting the scope:
- name: Set scope to system for myGroup if {{ module.name }} uses any
  xml:
    path: '{{ app_path }}/{{ module.name }}/pom.xml'
    namespaces:
      x: http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    xpath: '//x:dependency/x:groupId[text()="myGroup"]/../x:scope'
    value: system
  register: xmlfound
  when: java_files.matched
  failed_when:
    - xmlfound is failed
    - >-
      'in order to spawn nodes' not in xmlfound.msg

(The fiddling with failed_when is necessary, because lxml throws a fit over the xpath if it cannot find the matching dependencies.)
But how would I achieve the second part -- generating the systemPath based on the artifactId of each matching dependency?
Update: answering the questions in comments:

Yes, I'm fairly certain, I want to use Ansible -- the change is "mechanical", there little purchase in adding a new profile as it would just increase maintenance burden on developers, who build on their own desktops -- rather than the server -- and need the JARs downloaded from a repository. What I mean by "on the fly" is Ansible checking the sources out from git, massaging the pom.xml and invoking Maven -- locally, on each server meant to run these programs.
Yeah, I would use add_children, but what would the argument be? Each dependency's systemPath is different, derived from the artifactId.
Thanks for the xpath. Unfortunately, it still triggers errors for POMs without a single matching dependency, so I still need the failed_when hackery...


Are you sure you want to do that with Ansible and not Maven profiles designed for such tasks? Also, what do you mean by "on the fly"?

Use the same module. See add_children. But make sure you read Alexander's comment above before you proceed.

Just a small tip on your xpath: put the predicate on x:dependency so you don't have to navigate up and down again
like this: //x:dependency[x:groupId[text()="myGroup"]]/x:scope


"Yes, I'm fairly certain, I want to use Ansible -- the change is "mechanical", there little purchase in adding a new profile as it would just increase maintenance burden on developers, who build on their own desktops -- rather than the server" - the desired behavior is literally the purpose of Maven profiles. Being defined and/or enabled in settings.xml, they will provide it automatically. I'm not sure how injecting another tool into the build process to modify the sources (with custom error handling) is easier to maintain than a built-in standard solution.


pom.xml is under the purview of the developers here. I'm just automating the builds...

Disclaimer: this is only to answer the original question. To solve the problem, use Maven profiles instead.
Consider the following pom.xml example:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myGroup-agent-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.38.13</version>
            <classifier>yaml</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myGroup-another-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.79.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


But how would I achieve the second part -- generating the systemPath based on the artifactId of each matching dependency?

Unfortunately, this use case seems to be too complex for the xml module.
First, you have to get the list of those dependencies, and here's the trouble: the list of matches is flat. So you'll have to recreate the structure properly which is not a trivial task especially if your dependency nodes have uneven number of the nested nodes. Since I didn't operate XPath for years, maybe I use an incorrect one, but here's what I'm talking about (given a simplest pom.xml where 2 of 3 dependencies are on artifacts with "myGroup" groupId:
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Modify the pom.xml
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Find the dependencies on myGroup modules
      xml:
        path: 'pom.xml'
        namespaces:
          x: http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        xpath: '//x:dependency/x:groupId[text()="myGroup"]/..//*'
        content: text
      register: xmlfound

    - name: Show the results
      debug:
        var: xmlfound

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  xmlfound:
    actions:
      namespaces:
        x: http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
      state: present
      xpath: //x:dependency/x:groupId[text()="myGroup"]/..//*
    changed: false
    count: 8
    failed: false
    matches:
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}groupId': myGroup
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}artifactId': myGroup-agent-api
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version': 3.1.38.13
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}scope': provided
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}groupId': myGroup
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}artifactId': myGroup-another-api
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version': 3.5.79.0
    - '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}scope': provided
    msg: 8

And I'm not even talking about iterating over all the POMs in the projects, nested loops, and the fact that you need to use win_xml module if you have Windows machines.
Instead, you can use ansible.utils.from_xml filter to load the whole file, and then find the dependencies to process using selectattr Jinja filter:
# playbook.yaml
- name: Modify the pom.xml
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    vendor_group_id: myGroup
  tasks:
    - name: Read the pom.xml
      set_fact:
        current_pom: "{{ lookup('file', 'pom.xml') | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

    - name: Detect the dependencies to process
      set_fact:
        dependencies_to_process: >-
          {{
            current_pom.project.dependencies.dependency 
            | selectattr('groupId', 'equalto', vendor_group_id)
          }}

The next step is to use add_elements. The tricky parts here are the following:

it adds the elements only to the last match;
the added elements break the formatting. The pretty_print: true helps, but it changes the indentation from 4 spaces (typical for POMs) to 2 spaces;
it is not idempotent - so next time you run the playbook, it will add the systemPath nested node again.

To overcome this, you need to:

search for the artifactId nodes instead of groupId ones, iterating over the list built in the previous task;
add the systemPath nested node only if the list item does not contain it yet;
restore the formatting in the end using xmllint. Of course, this could (and generally should) be done using Ansible built-in modules such as replace, but in this case it would be too a complex task. The simplest solution would be to use ansible.utils.to_xml filter, but it will lose the comments if they were present.

Here's an almost (see notes below) full, idempotent example (note I used lstrip(vendor_group_id + "-") to define the path - it can differ in your case):
- name: Modify the pom.xml
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    vendor_group_id: myGroup
  tasks:
    - name: Read the pom.xml
      set_fact:
        current_pom: "{{ lookup('file', 'pom.xml') | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

    - name: Replace the scope
      set_fact:
        dependencies_to_process: >-
          {{
            current_pom.project.dependencies.dependency
            | selectattr('groupId', 'equalto', vendor_group_id)
          }}

    - name: Set scope to system for myGroup if uses any
      xml:
        path: 'pom.xml'
        namespaces:
          x: http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        xpath: '//x:dependency[x:groupId[text()="{{ vendor_group_id }}"]]/x:scope'
        value: system

    - name: Set systemPath for myGroup
      xml:
        path: 'pom.xml'
        namespaces:
          x: http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        xpath: '//x:dependency[x:artifactId[text()="{{ item.artifactId }}"]]'
        pretty_print: true
        add_children:
          - systemPath: >-
              ${application_path}/jar/{{ item.artifactId.lstrip(vendor_group_id + "-") }}.jar
      loop: '{{ dependencies_to_process }}'
      register: add_children_result
      when: item.systemPath is not defined

    - name: Restore the indentation
      environment:
        XMLLINT_INDENT: '    '
      command: 'xmllint pom.xml --output pom.xml --format'
      when: add_children_result is defined and add_children_result.changed

NOTES:

The fiddling with failed_when is necessary, because lxml throws a fit over the xpath if it cannot find the matching dependencies

I wouldn't say "necessary" as you can process the list of the matching dependencies as I suggested. Moreover, you probably want to add scope if there was no one set.
Important: I did not even take dependencyManagement into consideration for the sake of simplicity. As you might see, this solution is already overcomplicated even for a simple case.

Thanks, this is very similar to what I implemented. I say "necessary", when referring to the failed_when gymnastics, because the tasks fails for those POM-files, which don't have a single dependency using mygroup...

Since we're already iterating over the list of detected dependencies to add the systemPath element, we can apply the same approach for scope. That leads to the fact that we can move both actions to a block and only run it when the list is not empty.

I don't know, how to find the matches without getting an error, when no matches are found... A relatively minor problem, but still an open one...

It's what I do with the dependencies_to_process variable - take all the dependencies and select only those having "myGroup" as groupId. I didn't add the check on the list length to simplify the code but it could be added easily.

I see... Yeah, that's a way to do it. I still don't get, why the xml-module can't do that. I'm also worrying about the namespace -- what if Maven changes to .../POM/4.0.1 next year?


"what if Maven changes to .../POM/4.0.1 next year?" - That's one more good reason to stick with a standard solution. By the way, chances are that you will not even have access to the schema definition in restricted environments like CI servers - so you might need to adjust the xpath anyways. Regarding "why the xml-module can't do that" - there's a specific note in the documentation: "This module does not handle complicated xpath expressions, so limit xpath selectors to simple expressions." To simplify - it's just a generic module not designed to perform complex operations on Maven POM.


The restricted CI-servers is where the existing pom.xml is used. We do that out of inertia, primarily. I'm building on the actual application-servers, where the programs will be running: using Ansible to check code out from git, and then build it locally.

What's the point of CI in your organisation then? According to your comment, the CI environments, as well as any testing ones with all the efforts of QA team(s) seem to be wasted as you run not the same code that was tested.

Most of the Java-apps are deployed "normally" -- into Docker containers or into Tomcat. Just not these ones...

I'd prefer the Maven profiles solution mentioned by 
Alexander Pletnev in a comment to the question since this keeps your builds more independent from external tools/configurations:
First of all I'd store your myGroup-agent-api dependency in your:

internal Maven remote repository with deploy:deploy-file
or in your local Maven repository (if you don't have an internal remote one) with install:install-file

such being able to profit from Maven's usual dependency resolution.
Second, in your POM:

  <properties>
    <myGroup-agent-api.version>3.1.38.13</myGroup-agent-api.version>
  <properties>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>agent-provided</id>
      <!-- See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#details-on-profile-activation
          "All profiles that are active by default are automatically
          deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the
          command line or through its activation config."
      --> 
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
          <artifactId>myGroup-agent-api</artifactId>
          <version>${myGroup-agent-api.version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>agent-repo</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
          <artifactId>myGroup-agent-api</artifactId>
          <version>${myGroup-agent-api.version}</version>   
        </dependency>
      <dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...

Run mvn <phase> for a build with the dependency's <scope>provided.
Run mvn <phase> -P agent-repo for a build with the dependency resolved from your repository. The profile agent-provided will be deactivated then; see comment in the POM declaration above.
UPDATE
@Mikhail T.: Re your comment to this answer:

[...] the application [...] But, If the different processes each open their own copy, then RAM is wasted.

This sounds like premature optimization to me. JARs containing class code are in the (test or runtime) classpath and

[...] these Java classes aren’t loaded into memory all at once, but rather when they’re required by an application. This is where class loaders come into the picture. They’re responsible for loading classes into memory.

    – Baeldung, Class Loaders in Java
You're writing "the application" (in singular). So, where's the RAM issue?
See, for instance, the processes of my running Eclipse. There's just one JVM (PID 4068) started by Eclipse (PID 3968) (and another one by this JVM itself, which in this case is for spring-boot, but that's not necessarily so):
$ ps -dHo pid,cmd --cols 80 | egrep '(eclipse|jdk)'
  26775 grep -E (eclipse|jdk)
   3968 /home/geri/dev/eclipse/jee-2024-03/eclipse/eclipse
   4068   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-23.0.1/bin/java -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10 -Doomph.u
   4964     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-23.0.1/bin/java -Dsts.lsp.client=eclipse -Xmx1024m 


Thanks. I know, how to use profiles -- I just don't want to. I thought, there may be a Maven plugin, that can do the substitution automatically, but, if there is not, I'm perfectly willing to massage the pom.xml. The JARs in question come from the vendor and are used by their application itself. Storing a copy of each somewhere wastes both storage and runtime RAM.

@MikhailT. Well, you know, but potential future readers/seekers here perhaps don't. ;) Re "Storing ... somewhere": It's not somewhere, it's where Maven dependencies are ought to reside: in a Maven repository. How large are these dependencies and how does this waste additional "runtime RAM"?

There are 44 JARs provided by the application-vendor, sizes ranging from a few hundred Kb to tens of Mb. Because the application itself has each file open, opening the same path allows the kernel to share the data between multiple processes. But, If the different processes each open their own copy, then RAM is wasted.
This is also an argument against bundling all dependencies into a single large JAR for each program -- as seems to be the newbee developers' wont nowadays.
